# how to make events in clients system

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am doing a remote computing project in Java. Using the Robot class I am able to take the snapshot of client system. But how can I make events like mouse move, mouse click, key press in client system?

Comment: I have updated your question with some spelling and grammar corrections. Please take a few moments to make sure your questions have correct spelling and grammar from now on. It makes it easier for others understand and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look further down the JavaDocs for the Robot class.

Answer (score 1):

```
(new Robot()).mouseMove(x, y);

(new Robot()).mousePress( buttons );

(new Robot()).keyPress( keycode );
```